Issues with sum function in my SQL Query for SSRS report
I am currently working on expanding a rolling 365 revenue report to include data from two sources, our legacy ERP and our current ERP.  However, my report data is not displaying correctly, and from some testing that I've done, it appears that the SUM function in my query is not working as it should be.
Here's the first query that is working correctly, but only has data from the old system, I've also attached a picture of how the graph should look when working correctly:
how the data should look
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT o.LastInvoiceDate, o.InvoicedAmt,
    CASE 
        WHEN row_number() OVER (ORDER BY o.LastInvoiceDate) > 250
        THEN SUM(o.InvoicedAmt) OVER (ORDER BY o.LastInvoiceDate ROWS BETWEEN 250 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    END AS T365
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT so.LastInvoiceDate, SUM(so.InvoicedAmt) AS InvoicedAmt, NULL AS T365
        FROM dbo.SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader so
        WHERE LastInvoiceDate > DATEADD(MONTH, -25, GETDATE())
        GROUP BY so.LastInvoiceDate
        --ORDER BY so.LastInvoiceDate

    )o
)r
WHERE r.LastInvoiceDate >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
ORDER BY r.LastInvoiceDate

Here is how the data from this query looks
Graph as expected
Here is my new query, that I've built combining the data from the two different sources.
I've also attached a picture of the graph.  I can also see when running the query in SSMS that the value in the T365 column is gradually decreasing over the span of the year.  It's really bizarre.
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT o.InvoiceDate, o.InvoicedAmt,
    CASE 
        WHEN row_number() OVER (ORDER BY o.InvoiceDate) > 250
        THEN SUM(o.InvoicedAmt) OVER (ORDER BY o.InvoiceDate ROWS BETWEEN 250 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
        ELSE 0
    END AS T365
    FROM 
    (
    -- Query 1 (from sage100 database)
    SELECT 
        so.LastInvoiceDate AS InvoiceDate, 
        SUM(so.InvoicedAmt-so.FreightAmt) AS InvoicedAmt,
        NULL AS T365
    FROM MAS_TTI.dbo.SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader so
    WHERE so.LastInvoiceDate > DATEADD(MONTH, -25, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY so.LastInvoiceDate

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  CAST(h.ACCDAT_0 AS DATE) AS InvoiceDate,
    SUM
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN h.SIVTYP_0 = 'CRM' THEN d.AMTATILIN_0 * -1
            ELSE d.AMTATILIN_0 
        END) AS InvoicedAmt,
        NULL AS T365
    FROM x3.PROD.SINVOICE h
    INNER JOIN x3.PROD.SINVOICED d      ON d.NUM_0 = h.NUM_0
    INNER JOIN x3.PROD.ITMMASTER i      ON i.ITMREF_0 = d.ITMREF_0
    WHERE h.SIVTYP_0 IN ('INV','CRM','DIR') --No Proforma Invoices
    AND h.ACCDAT_0 > DATEADD(MONTH, -25, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY CAST(h.ACCDAT_0 AS DATE)
    )o
)r
WHERE r.InvoiceDate >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
ORDER BY r.InvoiceDate

New
Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?
I have tested multiple approaches on this query, originally I was even further off track, I don't have the specific examples of what I've tried, but what I've supplied is the closest I've been to having it working.
data with headers
how the data looks in new query - third column values slowly decreasing
more data, showing the values continually decreasing

You've not explained what your graph is doing, I assume it's grouping InvoicedAmt by date? Have you checked the results of the query to make sure they look OK? My first guess would be that it's to do with the fact you're making any CRM rows negative in the 2nd part of the query. Dump your query results into a temp table then select and group in the same way your graph should be and check the results, my guess is you will see the same decline

It's just a rolling 365 calculation of the SUM of the invoiced amounts for the past 365 days.  I did do that test, I'm seeing the same decline as is showing in the graph.  The negative for CRM is for credit memos, we don't want credit memos included in the invoice amount so it should be negative.

I don't have enough info to give an answer, but I can tell you how I would approach this:  make a copy/backup. Remove the part that works so you can isolate the problem. In your inner query for x3.PROD.SINVOICE, are you sure it is giving results comparable to MAS_TTI.dbo.SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader ?

@tgolisch I have uploaded pictures of the data that is being output from each query.  I couldn't figure out how to put the data in the post itself.

Decreasing amount? Looking at this statement WHEN h.SIVTYP_0 = 'CRM' THEN d.AMTATILIN_0 * -1, this could describe a decreasing amount, but I don't know what your data means. So I can't be sure. I would just look at why you need to multiply by -1.

Looking at the two queries, the part that gets data from SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader is different, the second version subtracts FreightAmt from InvoicedAmt but the first one doesn't, is this correct? You'll really need to supply sample data to work with, at the very least, the output from the UNION alias o. I used Azure Data Studio rather than SSMS and use the "save as Markdown" option, once saved you can copy the text into the question, better still would be to provide it as a create table/insert into script (or via a fiddle )
